# Delete multiple network interfaces in one call with AWS java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I have been trying to figure out how to delete multiple EC2 network interfaces using the AWS Java SDK. It is possible to select and delete multiple network interfaces in one operation in the AWS console, however, the [DeleteNetworkInterfaceRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DeleteNetworkInterfaceRequest.html) SDK method has no option to pass multiple IDs.

Is there a work around for this, apart from looping over the IDs?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Java SDK's [deleteNetworkInterface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#deleteNetworkInterface-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.DeleteNetworkInterfaceRequest-) method accepts only one [DeleteNetworkInterfaceRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DeleteNetworkInterfaceRequest.html), representing a single network interface.

The AWS console is probably making multiple API calls on your behalf, as a convenience.